# Laravel - Updating OneToOne relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have two models 'User' and 'Profile'.

'email' field is in User model whereas 'name' field is in Profile  model.

'profiles' table has a foreign key of 'user_id'.

I searched a lot but couldn't find a proper solution on how I can update both of these entities in one go.

In my ProfileController, I am doing this but I am sure there is a better way. Please help.

```
public function update($id)
{
    $profile = Profile::where('id', $id);
    $profile->name = 'Jon';
    $profile->save();

    $user = User::where('id', $profile->user_id);
    $user->email = 'newjon@example.com';
    $user->save();
}
```

My Profile model has

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```

And my User model has

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Profile');
}
```

Comment: Well you can use database triggers.

Comment: If the Profile has a hasOne relation with a user, and you've already found the profile, you could fetch the user by $profile->user; Which in terms, saves you another sql query.

Comment: Another thing is that one to one relationship doesn't make much sense to be in separate tables.

Comment: @pub_nub_qq - Actually there are many types of profiles each one with different columns so keeping them separate.

Comment: @Adimeus - That would save one select query. How do I get rid of the second insert query.

Comment: @Adimeus it won't save a query - `$profile->user` will call the query anyway.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk - No I guess that will be a single join query.

Comment: @aBhijit Your guess is wrong, Eloquent doesn't make any joins on relations. Read the source.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk - Oops. My bad. Any thoughts on how I can update both models in one go?

Comment: @aBhijit I guess your best bet is then table triggers. This would also make sure that if your table gets updated from elsewhere it is still going to update both tables. And on app level you can simply define models' properties by reference so updating one will update the other one as well.

Comment: @php_nub_qq - If you are talking about creating triggers at MySQL end, I frankly don't like the idea. Increases maintainability.

Comment: @aBhijit "increases maintainability" means it is going to be easier to maintain. I understand what you're trying to say, though, and I don't see how it is any different from an app-level implementation in terms of maintainability

Comment: @php_nub_qq - Yeah sorry, I wanted to say maintenance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it in one go.

However you could simplify it a bit, by leveraging Laravel features, like this (and do it in one-go-like way):

**1 Controller edit**

```
$profile = Profile::with('user')->find($id); 
// make sure you eager load the user for below to work
```

**2 View**

```
{{ Form::model($profile) }}
  {{ Form::text('name') }}
  {{ Form::text('user[email]') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

this will autopopulate your profile data (and user data too)

**3 Controller update**

```
$profile = Profile::find($id);
$profile->fill(Input::only(.. fields you want to update ..));
$profile->user->fill(Input::get('user')); // array of user data form the form
$profile->push(); // save both models in one go BUT separate queries
```

Also make sure you have `fillable` on your models, so `fill` will does its job.

---

Another way would be using `model events`, but I wouldn't do it that way.

Comment: Yeah, push() was what I needed. I read about it in the docs but it was they were not clear on how to use that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No prob, just mind that **you can't use push to insert multiple models** the same way. It will work only for existing models.

Comment: Basically parent of the relation (`hasOne`/`hasMany` side), of which id is referenced, must exist. You can't create relations for non-existing parent, since its id is `null` and Eloquent is not smart enough to fill it later on the children, when the parent is saved.